# How to randomly position a variable within X + Y = Z operation and loop

Tags: java, loops, variables, random

I basically want to be able to loop an X + Y = Z equation until the user inputs something other than an integer, like the letter "A" and also when having any number make the loop stop displaying a message.

Also, I am confused on how to randomly position the "?" which the user must input the correct answer.

For example

```
System.out.println("What is: " + num1 + " + ? = " + answer);
```

So far:

I am positioning the "?" manually through the IF statements. Can this be done in a more efficient way?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Random rand = new Random();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num1, num2, number3, answer;


    do {

        num1= 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
        num2= 1 + rand.nextInt(10);

        answer= num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("What is: " + num1 + " + ? = " + answer);

        number3= input.nextInt();

        if (number3 == num2)
            System.out.println("That is correct");
        else 
            System.out.println("That is wrong");

        num1= 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
        num2= 1 + rand.nextInt(10);

        answer= num1 + num2;

        System.out.println(num1 + " + ? = " + answer);

        number3= input.nextInt();

    } while(number3 !=0);       
}
```

Comment: Have you tried try/catch block to detect non-integer input?
e.g.
try{
   number3 = input.nextInt();
}catch(Exception e){
   break;
}

I haven't tested it out yet, but it looks like a good way to detect invalid input.

Comment: It looks like you are doing the same thing twice. The code looks like it repeats itself after your if..else statement. Maybe consider removing this. Can you elaborate on "I am positioning the "?" manually through the IF statements."?

Comment: `I am positioning the "?" manually through the IF statements.` No you are not, you're positioning `?` right where the print statement is positioning it. Basically what you want is to check that the input is any integer?

Comment: @Tuan333 I will try using the catch/try, thanks!

Comment: @clever_trevor Sorry for the confusion, I want to be able to change the position which the user sees where the "? " is. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1803551 Yes! I do want to check for any integers, else the console will printout a certain statement. Also, as I responded previously towards clever_trevor - I am trying to change the appearance of the "? " when the user sees it!

Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer for checking the input. You did not explain or demonstrate what you want with the "?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] xyz = new int[3];
    String[] display = new String[3];
    int answer, position;

    do {
        xyz[0] = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
        xyz[1] = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
        xyz[2] = xyz[0] + xyz[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < xyz.length; i++)
            display[i] = String.valueOf(xyz[i]);
        position = rand.nextInt(3);
        display[position] = "?";
        System.out.println("What is: " + display[0] + " + " + display[1] + " = " + display[2]);

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer or 'S' to stop");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("S")) {
                scanner.close();
                System.out.println("Stopped");
                return;
            }
            else if (input.matches("\\d+")) { // \\d+ means "a digit (0-9) once or more
                answer = Integer.parseInt(input);
                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        if (answer == xyz[position])
            System.out.println("That is correct");
        else
            System.out.println("That is wrong");
    } while (true);
}
```

**Notes:**

- I use an inner `do-while` loop to repeatedly check the input and ask the user for a valid input.
- I use 2 arrays: one for storing the numbers and another for storing the display values.
- I also added a stop condition since the outer loop is infinite. Always close the `Scanner` when you finish.
- I randomly pick 1 of 3 positions for the "?".

Comment: Thank you for your input!

However, as I have not really learnt the try and catch yet, I am seeking other ways to approach the problem.

One idea was, and I don't know if this is possible. I was thinking of creating a do-while loop and within that loop there is an if statement constantly checking for answers that are not integers. And also an keyboard input that prints a certain message. 

I am new to programming and do not know if there is such a syntax availible. For example: 

if user.input != integer;

   println ("Enter an integer please");

Comment: @Tor I don't see how this is related to the question "How to randomly position a variable within X + Y = Z operation and loop?". You have to be very clear on what you want exactly. Also you must tell us what you can use.